# Can Resharper learn to recognize linked files when refactoring?

Tags: refactoring, resharper

Is it possible to make resharper include linked files when refactoring?

Consider a solution setup with the following projects:

```
Backend
Services //Depends on 'Backend' and 'Services.Shared'
Services.Shared
Services.Shared.Silverlight //This project links all sourcecode in 'Services.Shared'
Frontend //Depends on 'Services.Shared' through 'Services.Shared.Silverlight'
```

When renaming a class in the 'Services.Shared' project, Resharper makes sure all is good and well in 'Services' and updates any references, but 'Frontend' which "indirectly" depends on 'Services.Shared', is not updated along with the refactoring.

Im aware that there is also problems with renaming of the file during refactor, since Resharper will rename the file in 'Services.Shared' making the link in 'Services.Shared.Silverlight' invalid.

But im wondering what people do, if anything at all, to make refactoring less painfull in this situation?

Comment: I've never seen this problem, all references to a renamed class get renamed in all project in a solution.

Comment: This happens when you use file linking (which should not be confused with simple using and assembly references). Like this: http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/01/20/linking-files-in-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say if it doesn't work now, that's an oversight that has been logged: http://bit.ly/ACucSI.  This seems related: [Visual Studio Linked Files Directory Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033990/visual-studio-linked-files-directory-structure)

Comment: You are right, this bug clearly indicates that it isnt handled yet. I hope they get around fixing it :-)